# Запретить запуск анимации щелчка SVG SMIL более одного раза

Tags: html, svg, анимация

У меня есть следующий SVG, который я анимирую с помощью SMIL - он отлично работает при щелчке, но будет повторяться при повторных щелчках - как я могу предотвратить это?

Я хочу, чтобы он **запускался только один раз**, а затем ничего не делал при следующем щелчке!

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <polygon points="60,60 90,120 30,120">
    <animateTransform
        id="at"
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        from="0 0"
        to="0 -39"
        dur="1s"
        begin="click"
        fill="freeze"/>
   
 </polygon>
</g> 
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Prevent SVG SMIL click animation from running more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64801457/7394871) от участника  [@Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14544753/tim).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64801457/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Установите для свойства `pointer-events` значение `none` в конце анимации, тогда дальнейшие щелчки мыши игнорируются

Значение `pointer-events="none"` устанавливается с помощью добавления второй анимации, которая начинается после окончания анимации движения `begin="at.end"`

```
 <set
        attributeName="pointer-events"
        to="none"
        begin="at.end"/>
```

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <polygon points="60,60 90,120 30,120">
    <animateTransform
        id="at"
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        from="0 0"
        to="0 -39"
        dur="0.5s"
        begin="click"
        fill="freeze"/>
   <set
        attributeName="pointer-events"
        to="none"
        begin="at.end"/>
 </polygon>

</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64801996/7394871) от участника  [@Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрите другие варианты запрета повторной анимации после клика:

[**restart = "whenNotActive"**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/restart)

> Это значение указывает, что анимацию можно перезапустить только тогда,
> когда она неактивна (то есть после активного окончания). Попытки
> перезапустить анимацию во время ее активной продолжительности
> игнорируются.

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <polygon points="60,60 90,120 30,120">
    <animateTransform
        id="at"
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        from="0 0"
        to="0 -39"
        dur="1s"
        begin="click"
        fill="freeze"
        restart="whenNotActive"/>
    </polygon>
</svg>
```

[**restart = "never"**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/restart)

> Это значение указывает, что анимация не может быть перезапущена на
> время загрузки документа.

Другими словами анимация срабатывает только один раз, повторный запуск невозможен.
Снова запустить анимацию можно только после перезагрузки документа.

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <polygon points="60,60 90,120 30,120">
    <animateTransform
        id="at"
        attributeName="transform"
        type="translate"
        from="0 0"
        to="0 -39"
        dur="1s"
        begin="click"
        fill="freeze"
        restart="never"/>
 </polygon>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64820703/7394871) от участника  [@Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7394871/alexandr-tt).</sub>